# How to keep Mac OSX Notifications Panel Open?

Tags: notifications, macos-sierra

How to keep Mac OSX Notifications Panel Open?!

The sidebar Notifications panel how to keep this open and not close.

Comment: Keep it open after having clicked somewhere else, or…? You do know that this overlaps other windows. Also, what are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Keep it open all the time (So it does not close). Yeah it overlaps but you can move the windows and adjust them so it doesn't overlap.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is keep it open... so I can have widgets visible all the time like a side bar. So I don't forget tasks... Does anyone know of a Dock/sidebar that you can keep open on the right side of the screen?